# Blender : How to select only viewable objects?

Tags: python, 3d, blender, raycasting, zbuffer

On a blender environment (You need Blender installed on your machine), I am looking for a way to select objects based on a point of view, I don't want to select hidden objects.
It is based on python language and blender library, you can run your script directly on your blender's scripting console, it is entirely based on python.

The only criteria is that it is based on a scene with multiple objects of multiple shapes, some hides others, depending on your point of view or your camera, with a relatively "adjustable" precision.

I have learned that some ways exists to obtains this result :

Z buffer, you get a list of distances based on each rendered pixels, it seems working with a method called "depth_pixels.reshape((height, width, value))", but I don't really know why using the red canal make the estimated distance viable ..

The viewport selector called "bpy.ops.view3d.select_box", It seems based on a space detection, so I am not sure if there is a way to restrict the selection on "viewable" objects
[text](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/search.html?q=select_box&check_keywords=yes&area=default)

Raycasting, also available on blender, you throw ray on a specific direction, and you can get back the collided objet, but it's very performance consuming

Polygons selection, it seems that you can calculate the orientation of each faces and select these specific polygons, maybe there is a way to select the corresponding objet that carry these polygons ?

I am not a specialist, so I don't know the specification to use these function on the blender's console, if anyone have idea or know how to use these functions ?

Maybe even other options exists, I don't know,

Thanks in advance,